# Attachments in pdf

Tags: c#, pdf

i have various pdf files say file1.pdf, file2.pdf..........
Now I want to create a new pdf document say MainDoc.pdf.
And this MainDoc.pdf will contain File1.pdf,File2.pdf... as attachments.

Tried this code  but it is giving error :
"`Object Refrence not set to an instance`"

```
its.Document PDFD = new its.Document(its.PageSize.LETTER);
its.pdf.PdfWriter writer;
writer = its.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(PDFD, new FileStream(targetpath, FileMode.Create));
its.pdf.PdfFileSpecification pfs = its.pdf.PdfFileSpecification.FileEmbedded(writer, "C:\\test.xml", "New.xml", null);
writer.AddFileAttachment(pfs);
```

It Looks like issue is with writer.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.get_PdfIndirectReference()

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: i am having the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Null is from the document.

Add

`PDFD.Open();`

after

`its.pdf.PdfWriter writer = its.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(PDFD, new FileStream(targetpath, FileMode.Create));`

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that 'writer' and 'PdfFileSpecification' isn't null?

Comment: Hi Andre

 Writer is not null I have checked.
AND its.pdf.PdfFileSpecification is a class and "FileEmbedded" is a STATIC function. So it can be called by Instance of PdfFileSpecification class. For Ex.:
its.pdf.PdfFileSpecification.FileEmbedded

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the error occurrs on that last line? Check `pfs` - was it allocated?

```
its.Document PDFD = new its.Document(its.PageSize.LETTER);
its.pdf.PdfWriter writer = its.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(PDFD, new FileStream(targetpath, FileMode.Create));
its.pdf.PdfFileSpecification pfs = its.pdf.PdfFileSpecification.FileEmbedded(writer, "C:\\test.xml", "New.xml", null);
if( pfs )
{
    writer.AddFileAttachment(pfs);
}
else
{
    // An error occurred!
}
```

Comment: hi jon,
        I am writing this code. And Error is coming on "pfs = its.pdf.PdfFileSpecification.FileEmbedded" line.
    Error is :Object Ref not set to instance of object

    Please suggest

    writer = its.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(PDFD, new FileStream(targetpath, FileMode.Create));
    its.pdf.PdfFileSpecification pfs;
    pfs = its.pdf.PdfFileSpecification.FileEmbedded(writer, "D:\\Test.xml", "Driving.pdf",null);

    if (pfs!=null)
    {
    writer.AddFileAttachment(pfs);
    }
    else
    {
    Response.Write("Err");
    }

Comment: It Looks like issue is with writer.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.get_PdfIndirectReference()